# Unterminated group despite escaping parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to create a regular expression, which matches left parenthesis. However, when I run:

```
new RegExp("\(")
```

in Node's repl, I get:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group

Why is the backslash not escaping the left parenthesis?

Comment: Check `console.log("\(")` and you will see there is no backslash.

Comment: Tried using two backslashes new RegExp("\\\(") ?